# Raspbian Buster: Forcing a Terminal Window for a Python Script @ startup

Tags: python, bash, terminal, autostart, raspbian-buster

Running Raspbian Buster on an RPi3B+.

Have a good autostart running at /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi which calls a bash script called launcher.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

sleep 10  # Just giving time for other stuff to settle in.
/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Desktop/HOSTCORE/SpeechCenter.py &
#Listens (binds) to :5555 for speech to input
sleep 55

/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Desktop/HOSTCORE/visionCommandTest.py
#Talks to :5555 for speech to output
sleep 10
```

The first call to SpeechCenter.py works perfectly, running in the background, and the system announces it is connected to the Speech Center.

I need the second call, visionCommandTest.py, to run in a terminal window, so the user can input text for the system to speak, but the command does not open a terminal window.  The command IS working because a ps -ax reveals that python visionCommandTest.py is running with (in this case) "PID 934 pts/0 Tl" - however, without it opening a terminal window, there is no ability for user input.  (Also, SpeechCenter.py shows a PID of "911 ? Sl"... so there's definitely a difference in the way they show up in my ps -ax listing)

Just need to know how to tell the bash script to open a terminal window and then run visionCommandTest.py in it...

Thanks!

Comment: `xterm -e command` ? Or maybe `LXTerminal`

Comment: lxterminal -e /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Desktop/HOSTCORE/visionCommandTest.py did the trick, thanks!

Comment: Just an aside....  All of this stuff was working perfectly in Raspbian Stretch, but Buster came along and changed the location of autostart and the behavior of bash scripts....  Gotta love it 